# A function which when differentiated, acts like two power laws

Tags: functions, derivatives

Hard to explain via the title, but i'm looking for a function which behvaes similarly to $x^n$ when differentiated.

$\frac{d^m x^n}{dx^m} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} x^{n-m}$

I'm looking for a function $f(x)$ which acts like

$\frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n} = \frac{a!}{(a-n)!} \frac{b!}{(b-n)!} g_n(x)$

For all $n < a, b$.

Comment: The right side contains $a,b$ which are not in either of $f(x),g(x).$ What values should they have in terms of $n$, or are you thinking they should be some two functions of $n$ to be specified in any particular example?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ should just be constants, with no dependence on $x$. The functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can be anything, provided they fill the constraint of the nth derivative for all n.

Comment: I'm confused: the exponentiation does not satisfy a property similar to the one you wrote: in fact there exists no *fixed* $g(x)$ such that $\dfrac{d^m}{dx^m}[x^n]=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}g(x)$ for all $m< n$. In fact, $x^{n-m}$ depends on which $m$ you are considering!

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear in that I don't care about what g(x) is. I'll edit it such that it's now $g_n(x)$